# How can one generally prevent silly mistakes in very long physics calculations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, soft-question, education

I am a student working on certain open-ended research problems in quantum systems that mostly have long calculations and deal with a large number of terms. I tend to make a lot of silly mistakes despite taking utmost care not to do so. By the time I discover I have made a mistake, I have to begin everything from scratch. This takes up a lot of useful time and is extremely frustrating. Also since these are open-ended problems I cannot refer to anything to check whether my calculations are correct.

Is there something I can do or practice to prevent such things?

Comment: Personally, I use a symbolic computation program such as Wolfram Mathematica. You can break the problem up into chunks that you can compute and adjust if you spot a sign error (for example) and when you correct the error, it will cascade through the rest of the calculation.

Comment: When I was in grad school, a very successful and prominent faculty member advised:  "Don't skip steps."   I doubt that the following applies to anyone at your level, but I find when teaching novice undergrads, they often execute algebraic steps by crossing out and/or appending factors to both sides.  That is, writing the factors directly on the expression in front of them.   In addition to risking error, these practices make it *impossible* to find errors,  or when grading exams, figure out what the student was trying to do, and where it went wrong.  Can't give partial credit!

Comment: As much as this is a common issue for most people doing physics (or any mathematics) I must VTC as opinion based as what works for one person won't necessarily work for another.

Comment: @StephenG I have edited the question to make it more generalized and objective.

Answer (score 3):

What I do is, before beginning super long multi-part calculations, I establish certain conditions that must be upheld by the equations at each step. For example units, or symmetry in certain variables.

In a calculation I'm doing right now, I spent a couple days working out an important simple case in excruciating detail. Now that I'm doing the full calculation, I can map each stage of the calculation to the simple one and make sure I get the right answer in the appropriate simplifying limit.

This is similar to debugging in programming, doing sanity checks along the way.

Comment: [Related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_check) [concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing).

Comment: *whereas in coding you can afford to do all these sanity checks at the end and adjust your code accordingly.* I disagree. The problem is still the same. It's not enough to know you went wrong. You need to know where. I am not sure how you're able to debug just knowing you tripped up somewhere in the hundreds or thousands of lines of code prior. Maybe you're a genius but don't realize it. But then you wouldn't need those step-wise sanity checks in math either.

Comment: @DKNguyen In my experience, errors in code are much more isolated than in calculations, in the sense that, if you find you made a mistake in a subroutine that you wrote an hour ago, that mistake won't propagate down through everything you've written. Whereas in calculations even a small minus sign that you missed an hour ago can propagate downwards and affect everything you wrote afterwards. I agree though, that  in code of course we do sanity checks along the way, but in calculations it seems more crucial.

Comment: @DKNguyen I edited that part of my answer to reflect what you said.

Comment: Sounds like you're saying something more like you often know the correct end result in programming (because you decide what you want it to do after all) rather than in math.

Comment: @DKNguyen I guess that's largely true, yeah. Hadn't thought of it like that.

Comment: Oh, yes. I see what you mean by error isolation vs propagating errors.

Answer (score 1):

I personally find organization and alternate methods help me avoid my mistakes. When working on long calculations, I'll often split my equation into numbered chunks. Below the equation, I'll label the section I'm working on, then solve it in a very organized manner (generally one line per step with apparent algebraic steps). I'll then double check my work, and if there's an alternate method of solving it, I will go through that one too and check both my answers. For intermediate steps, I box or star important equations I may need later. Be really careful and double or triple check negative signs. Hope this helps.